# what is the name for the space between the leaves of a tree

Tags: terminology, trees, binary-trees, number-theory

I am trying to write a data-type not for a tree, but for the spaces *in between* the leaves of thee tree.  In number theory (a part of math) this is known as a **topograph** does it have a name in CS?

[image]

Comment: CS is also (a part of math). As far as I know, there is no name specific to computer science. I don't think there has ever been a CS-specific use-case though.

Comment: For the "spaces between leaves" to be well defined, the tree needs to be an *ordered* tree (a tree in which the children of a vertex have some ordering).  This is very often what programmers and computer scientists mean when they talk about "trees", but strictly speaking, an ordering of children is not necessary for a tree.

Answer (score -1):

Each 3 leaves form a glob so I just figured out what a cluster means.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

The empty space is called "OTIOSE".   Pronounced "oh-she-ohs"

otiosity

Synonyms & Antonyms for otiose 
Synonyms
abortive, barren, bootless, empty, fruitless, futile, ineffective, ineffectual, inefficacious, profitless, unavailing, unproductive, unprofitable, unsuccessful, useless, vain

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Do you have a citation or an example to show someone else who uses this word this way?

Comment: I see no evidence that this term is used. None of the synonyms you give is at all relevant to the question, so I don't see why "otiose" itself should be.